# JAX-WS Handler Dispatching Problem

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-ws

I have implemented a SOAPHandler which updates the content of the SOAPBody. The handler is used on the server side for inbound processing (content decryption).
I get the exception:

```
<S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
     <faultcode>S:Client</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Cannot find dispatch method for {}</faultstring>
  </S:Fault>
```

The handler creates the following SOAPEnvelope:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<soapenv:Body xmlns:rp="http://rp/">
    <rp:add xmlns="http://rp/">
        <arg0>2</arg0>
        <arg1>4</arg1>
    </rp:add>
</soapenv:Body>
```

My webservice is implemented as follows:

```
@HandlerChain(file = "HandlerChain_RL.xml")

@SOAPBinding(style=SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://rp/")
public class RL {
@WebMethod(action="add", operationName="add2")
public int add(@WebParam int a, @WebParam int b) {
    return a + b;
}}
```

Do I have to dispatch manually etc.?? Thank you in advance :-)